Interpreting convolution and integral of function's product as an overlap-measure?
Background
Both the integral of the product of functions and the more general convolution are called 'overlap' (Wikipedia).
Also MathSE article tells so.
In a convolution, the one function is shifted, so it's a cumulative overlap, or rather the overlap at a time $t$.
Wikipedia shows what overlapping means in an image, but that's not what integral does:

Integrating product of 2 functions is the area of the product. This is: not the shared area.
The overlap between two functions is the shared area between two functions, this is not equal to $1$.

Example
Take a simple example of $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$ then the integral between 0 and 1 becomes $x^4/4$ which is $1/4$ but the shared area is clearly $x^3/3$ which is $1/3$.
One possibility is that overlap is just defined with the integral of the product, but then, graphically that's not the area between the functions.
What am I missing?

This is not what is meant by "overlap"; it's not a technical term, just giving an intuitive idea. It's like a generalization of the dot product which, loosely speaking, measures "correlation" between two vectors.

@QiaochuYuan, they highlight the shared area, which is my main criticism. Same with orbitals (1st link)

Convolution is definitely not the overlapping (to mean intersection) area. It's more like when they overlap, what's the area of the product in the overlapping region. This is only evident if one or both the functions are zero beyond a finite point on the real axis. If both functions are non-zero, they will always overlap, no matter how much you shift. But the area of the product of overlap can become zero as a limit of the shift going to infinite in a direction

Yeah but my whole point is that any integral between 2fns is not the area of intersection and i show an example. I dont see what your point is tbh @Srini. If you integrate x times x^2 between 0 and 1 thats not the intersection. It is the area of a different function! Ig "the area of the product in the overlapping region" means we agree. But not what wikipedia shows graphically!

Yes, we agree. If you are referring to this picture from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#/media/File:Comparison_convolution_correlation.svg, the area of shaded portion (i.e. intersection ALSO happens to be the area of the product because the function $f$ is a unitbox/rect function whose value is $1$. In that sense, they chose an example that is a very special case of the convolution, where both the meanings are same (but not true for general functions). Hope this clears the confusion. If you are ok with this explanation, I will post it as an answer.

For the case of functions defined on real axis,
Convolution is defined as follows:
$$[f(x) \star g(x)](p) = \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(p-x) dx =  \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} f(p-x) g(x) dx$$
When we convolve two functions, we need to flip/mirror one of the functions around vertical axis, shift it right by $p$ (or left for negative $p$) and take the integral of the product of this flipped+shifted function and the other function (unmodified). The convolution result will be a function of the shift (i.e. $p$).
Let's talk about overlap and intersection area using 3 cases (though to be complete we need to list more cases, which I will skip for now).

Case 1:  $g(x)$ is non-zero over the entire real line.

Example: $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ and $g(x) = e^{-2|x|}$.
$$f \star g = \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} e^{-2|y-x|} dx = \frac23 (2 e^{-|y|} - e^{-2|y|})$$
Here, the two functions (after flip+shift) always overlap. As a limit $y \to \pm \infty$, $f \star g \to 0$, as intuitively, the product of the decaying functions becomes lesser and lesser after integration (indicating that our way of measuring ovelap with convolution is not the same as there being any ovelap at all, which in this case is always). Also in this case, the intersection area (which is piecewise orange-only dependent and blue-only dependent, based on which function is smaller in the a given sub-interval of the overlap, note: not fully showing all intersections in the right of the picture) is not the same as the integral of the product.


Case 2:  $g(x)$ is non-zero over an interval and is not a constant in that interval.
Example: $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ and $g(x) = \operatorname{Tri}(x)$ (unit triangle function).

$$f \star g = \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} \operatorname{Tri}(y-x) dx$$ (The convolution result is piecewise and can be computed, but I am skipping). Here again, the functions always overlap. And similar to case $1$, the convolution integral will tend to $0$ with large magnitude shifts and the intersection area is not the same as the convolution.

Case 3: g(x) is non-zero only in an interval and is also a constant.
Example: $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ and $g(x) = \operatorname{Rect}(x)$ (unit box function).

$$f \star g = \int\limits_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} \operatorname{Rect}(y-x) dx$$ (The convolution result is piecewise and can be computed, but I am skipping). Here again, the functions always overlap. And similar to case $1$, the convolution integral will tend to $0$ with large magnitude shifts.  But intersection area is the same as the convolution. This is due to the simple fact that unit box is defined as
$$\operatorname{Rect}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & -\frac12 \le x \le \frac12\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$ and one of the functions in the product is $1$ in the interval (and importantly $|f(x)| \le |g(x)|$ in the overlap area) .
$\color\green{\text{This is the type of example shown in Wikipedia, causing confusion}}$.$\color\green{\text{In the general case, intersection area is not a property of convolution.}}$

thank you, normally Rect is called Indicator function right?
